# Point cloud software

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

Where can I find software for creating point clouds similar to MS Photosynth without being a programmer.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about this kind of things?: http://pointclouds.org

Answer (score 3):

### Creating Point Clouds with Gimp

We have no idea how Photosynth works. With **[The Gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gimp)**

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

you can create point clouds very easily:

#### Load a picture with Gimp:

[image]

#### Reduce Colours

Choose *Image -> Mode -> Indexed* from the menu and then reduce to black and white 1-bit palette using dithering:

[image]

#### Point Cloud Result

[image]

Comment: I think it is not the same "point cloud" feature as he is asking for, see http://pointclouds.org/

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul: Indeed, I am pretty sure this is not the *Point Cloud* we are looking for here - however I was unable to find out how Photosynth is in any way connected to 3D meshes or "clouds". So there you go with a point clouded Narwhal ;)